# Audio recorder with UpLoad function- Why does "var myRecording" not contain any recording?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, makefile, audio-recording, titanium-mobile

I am working on a simple audio recording code that takes the recorded audio and let another upload function -upload it to a web server. The code is based on KitchenSinks audio recorder. The problem is that it seems that "var myRecording" does not contain the recording. What does my code miss? How can I get the recording file, store it and again get it and upload it? Is there a audio recorder/uploader example out there?
Here is some of my code:

```
var myRecording = null;

var buttonUpload = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Upload Recording'
});

Titanium.Media.audioSessionMode = Ti.Media.AUDIO_SESSION_MODE_PLAY_AND_RECORD;
var recording = Ti.Media.createAudioRecorder();

recording.compression = Ti.Media.AUDIO_FORMAT_ULAW;
recording.format = Ti.Media.AUDIO_FILEFORMAT_WAVE;

Ti.Media.addEventListener('recordinginput', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('Input availability changed: '+e.available);
    if (!e.available && recording.recording) {
        b1.fireEvent('click', {});
    }
});

var file;
var sound;

var b1 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'Start Recording',
    width:200,
    height:40,
    top:20
});

b1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (recording.recording)
    {
        file = recording.stop();
        var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(file.path);
        var m = f.move(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory + '/audio.m4a');
        b1.title = "Make New Recording";
        b2.show();
        pause.hide();
    }
    else
    {
        if (!Ti.Media.canRecord) {
            Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                title:'Error!',
                message:'No microphone is found.'
            }).show();
            return;
    }
        b1.title = "Stop Recording";
        recording.start();
        b2.hide();
        pause.show();       
    }
});
win.add(b1);

var pause = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'Pause Recording',
    width:200,
    height:40,
    top:80
});
win.add(pause);
pause.hide();

pause.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (recording.paused) {
        pause.title = 'Pause Recording';
        recording.resume();
    }
    else {
        pause.title = 'Continue Recording';
        recording.pause();
    }
});

var b2 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'Play recording',
    width:200,
    height:40,
    top:80
});

win.add(b2);
b2.hide();
b2.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (sound && sound.playing)
    {
        sound.stop();
        sound.release();
        sound = null;
        b2.title = 'Play recording';
    }
    else
    {
        Ti.API.info("recording file size: "+file.size);
        sound = Titanium.Media.createSound({sound:file});
        if(Ti.Platform.osname == 'iphone'){
        win.rightNavButton = buttonUpload;
        }else{
        buttonUpload.right = 20;
        buttonUpload.top = 20;
        }
        sound.addEventListener('complete', function(){
            b2.title = 'Play recording';
        });
        sound.play();
        b2.title = 'Stop Playback';

    }
});

buttonUpload.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        myRecording = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, '/audio.m4a');
        if(myRecording != null) {
        myPostFunction();
        }else{
        alert('Nothing is recorded!');
        }
});

function myPostFunction(){ continues here…
```

Comment: Have you checked your console for error messages?

Comment: Are you testing this on a device? This wont work on the Simulator.

Comment: I am testing it on a iPhone-device and the upload progress works, but it is to fast and I got the message that nothing is saved on the server. I suspect that "var myRecording" is empty or without the recording and that it have not found or catched my audio. Is there another way to grab the audio from the KitchenSinks audio recorder? I can't find any other audio recording sample application(iOS) to learn from. Anyone that you know of?